# ¿Por qué no me permite actualizar el usuario con el método update pero si recogerlo con el findOrFail?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7

El código es el siguiente:

```
$creado= (Usuario::create([
        'usu_username' => $data['usu_username'],
        'usu_no'=> '0',
        'usu_rol' => '1',
        'usu_fecha_incorporacion' => Carbon::now('Europe/London')->toDateTimeString(),
        'usu_clave' => bcrypt($data['usu_clave']),
        'usu_activo'=> '1',
    ]))?true:false;

    $usuario2=DB::table('usuario')->orderBy('id_usuario', 'desc')
        ->first();

    $usuarioid=Usuario::findOrFail($usuario2->id_usuario);
    $usuario2->usu_no=$usuarioid->id_usuario+1;
    $creado=($usuario2::update())?true:false;
```

Y mi usuario es del tipo:

```
namespace libreir;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Usuario extends Authenticatable

{
    use Notifiable;

protected $table='usuario';

protected $primaryKey='id_usuario';

public $timestamps=false;
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'usu_no', 'usu_username', 'usu_rol', 'usu_clave', 'usu_fecha_incorporacion', 'usu_activo', 'usu_cliente_id', 'usu_admin_id'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'usu_clave', 'remember_token',
];
```

Mi error es el siguiente:
[image: Call to undefinied method stdClass::update()]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a colaborar un poco reescribiendo ligeramente el código y explicando la razón por la cual no funciona lo que intentabas hacer:

Antes que nada no entiendo el punto (me falta contexto del proyecto) para tener una especie de "flag" si un usuario fue creado o no. Evaluando el resultado de la variable que recibe el resultado de la creación obtengo el mismo efecto, no considero necesario generar un boolean.

```
$creado = Usuario::create([
    'usu_username' => $data['usu_username'],
    'usu_no'=> '0',
    'usu_rol' => '1',
    'usu_fecha_incorporacion' => Carbon::now('Europe/London')->toDateTimeString(),
    'usu_clave' => bcrypt($data['usu_clave']),
    'usu_activo'=> '1',
]) ? true : false;
```

La siguiente línea no tiene mucha coherencia teniendo en cuenta que estamos usando Eloquent en la línea anterior:

> $usuario2 = DB::table('usuario')->orderBy('id_usuario', 'desc')
>           ->first();

Sería mejor usar Eloquent entonces:

```
$usuario2 = Usuario::orderBy('id_usuario', 'desc')->first();
```

Siguiendo con las buenas prácticas de Laravel, la siguiente línea también sería incorrecta, pues en teoría estoy encontrando un usuario a partir de la clave primaria del mismo usuario que ya obtuve, o sea, estoy buscando el usuario que ya tengo (???), básicamente esta línea sobra, y por cierto, el nombre de la variable es poco coherente con lo que contiene (un perfil, pero el nombre dice que contiene un id):

> $usuarioid = Usuario::findOrFail($usuario2->id_usuario);

En la siguiente línea asumo que intentas agregar una especie de llave foránea (?) por medio de un incremento, el cual puede realizarse simplemente con el operador respectivo, incluso y dependiendo del contexto, Laravel tiene otras opciones para hacer más "limpia" esta parte:

> $usuario2->usu_no = $usuarioid->id_usuario+1;

Algo levemente mejor sería:

```
$usuario2->usu_no = $usuarioid->id_usuario++;
```

**Y por último, el update no funciona porque NO es un método estático y además update() REQUIERE pasarle los parámetros que se desean actualizar:**

> $creado = $usuario2::update() ? true : false;

El método que deberías haber utilizado para no pasarle los parámetros, era  save():

```
$creado = $usuario2->save() ? true : false;
```

Una vez más, no entiendo el boolean.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu explicación, es bueno aprender cuales son las mejores prácticas de laravel. Con tu duda del boolean, era solo para ver si hacía lo que yo le pedía, una manera simple de verlo en el xdebuger.

Answer (score 0):

```
$usuario2=DB::table('usuario')->orderBy('id_usuario', 'desc')
        ->first();

    $creado=(DB::table('usuario')->where('id_usuario',$usuario2->id_usuario)->update(['usu_no' => $usuario2->id_usuario+1]))?true:false;
```

Con este código donde quería poner el update he conseguido actualizar sin que me diera el error, no se por qué pero funciona que es lo que quería. Espero que les sirva.